# Create a Login screen via SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am new to Salesforce. I need to create a Login screen where users will first register with the system and then use these credentials to login to the system.

All these information should be saved on to a DB. I need to know how can i do this ? A tutorial/video tutorial or steps would help me start with this. Help ?

Comment: Salesforce already has it's own user model. Depending on what you're going to use it for, you have different users types. What is the usage scenario?

Comment: No, i want to Customize the login screen. i need to have my own logo, and text on it. is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about for your regular users then no, this isn't possible. If you're talking about customers then I believe what you're looking for (from the scant details provided) is [customer portal](http://www.salesforce.com/crm/customer-service-support/customer-self-service-portal/).

Be aware though, that there are licence fees involved with this and writing your own user authentication system is against the terms of service.